# Stress test serial port, any available software?

Tags: linux

A client of mine wants to ensure that the linux box I'm working on can handle receiving data at 115200 bits/s on a serial port without losing any data.

Is there any software available for doing this, or am I going to have to roll my own?

Comment: I'd probably roll my own.. Can't be that hard.. knock up a quick script in python, or just on the shell, squirt data into /dev/ttyS0 as fast as you can.

Comment: I think it would be hard to find a system built in the last 5 years not capable of handling that speed.

Comment: @symcbean, underpowered serial ports are still common in the embedded space. Or there might be problems under high load dropping bytes - remember a standard 16550 UART will need to serviced every few bytes or so.  If the interrupts are starved of CPU, this might well happen.

Answer (score 2):

[socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) can use serial ports.  Once that pipe is established, you can pipe into it whatever you want, at whatever rate you want.  The simplest test would be to do something along the lines of:

```
pv /dev/zero | socat <options>
```

pv would tell you the rate at which you're piping the data.

Answer (score 1):

here's an archaic testing program that mentions testing serial lines (and everytime i read that part i wonder who would ever do that):
http://www.scsifaq.org/RMiller_Tools/dt.html

but really, all you need is a program that can generate some data, and then verify it was received correctly... you could just aswell transfer some large file and verify it's integrity afterwards...
(and if you push data over a serial port and don't have flow control enabled, it's going to be transfered exactly at the rate the port is configured to, or get corrupted, so it's not possible that performance is only degraded)

Answer (score 1):

You may find the following tool to be useful (I have used it for this exact purpose):
https://github.com/cbrake/linux-serial-test

To be specific, you can stress a serial port with the following command:

```
linux-serial-test -s -e -p /dev/ttyS2 -b 115200
```

Use with a serial loopback cable.  It will report any errors that it sees (-e), and a running log every 5 seconds or so (-s), if desired.